# Links autogenerated by joomla with the incorrect domain

Tags: redirect, joomla, hyperlink, dns

I have a Hosting in Hostgator with the domain http://vector5.eu set as principal. Also, I have a Joomla installed here: http://vector5.eu/responcat.

Then there is a domain (which I don't belong, belongs to another company): http://respon.cat. This domain have this redirection pointing to my Joomla:

```
http://respon.cat/newsletter --> http://vector5.eu/responcat
```

My problem is that this Joomla is not autogenerating the links with the domain http://respon.cat, instead they are generated with the domain http://vector5.eu.

This is an example of one link on the webpage: http://vector5.eu/responcat/index.php/newsletter-en-catala

I've tried almost everything with no luck. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please add an example with the requested url and where you want it to redirect.

Comment: If you access to: http://www.respon.cat/newsletter you'll see a menu on the right called "Newsletter" with only 1 element in the menu. This element links to an URL that have for domain "vector5.eu/..." instead of "respon.cat/newsletter/...".

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the menu item that creates this link.